# How smart is the Java JVM about GC'ing during a reduce() operation on a long Scala list or Stream?

Tags: java, scala, stream, garbage-collection, jvm

OK, let me see if I can explain.

I have some code that wraps a Java iterator (from Hadoop, as it happens) in a Scala Stream, so that it potentially can be read more than once, by client code that I have no direct control over.  The last thing that gets done with this Stream is a reduce() operation.  Stream remembers all the items that it's already seen.  Unfortunately, in some circumstances the iterator will be extremely large, so that storing all the items in it will lead to out-of-memory errors.  However, in general, the situations where the client code needs the multiple-iteration facility are not the same ones with the memory-busting Iterators, and if such cases do exist, that's not my problem.

What I want to ensure is that I can provide the memoizing capability for code that needs it, but not for code that doesn't need it (in particular, for code that never looks at the Stream at all).

The code for reduce() in Stream says that it's written in a way to allow for GC of the already-visited parts of the Stream to happen *while* reducing.  So if I can make sure this actually happens, I'll be fine.  But in practice how can I make sure that this happens?  In particular, if function A creates and passes the stream to function B, and function B passes the stream to function C, and function C then calls reduce(), then what about the references to the stream still in functions A, B and C?  In all these cases, there will be no further use of the stream in any of the three functions, although the calls aren't necessarily tail-recursive.  Is the JVM smart enough to ensure that its reference count is 0 from functions A, B and C at the time that reduce() is called, so that the GC can happen?  Essentially this means that the JVM notices in function A that the last thing it does with the item is call function B, so it eliminates its own handle at the same time it calls B, and likewise for B to C, and C to reduce().

If this works properly, does it also work if A, B or C has a local variable holding onto the item? (Which, again, won't be used, afterwards.) That's because it's rather more tricky to code this properly without using local vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable which is in scope but which will never be read from is *dead*. A JVM is free to ignore dead variables for the purposes of garbage collection; an object which is only pointed to by dead variables is unreachable, and may be collected. The relevant bit of the JLS is, obscurely enough, [§12.6.1 Implementing Finalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1), which says:

> A reachable object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread.

And explains that:

> Optimizing transformations of a program can be designed that reduce the number of objects that are reachable to be less than those which would naively be considered reachable. For example, a Java compiler or code generator may choose to set a variable or parameter that will no longer be used to null to cause the storage for such an object to be potentially reclaimable sooner.
>
> Another example of this occurs if the values in an object's fields are stored in registers. The program may then access the registers instead of the object, and never access the object again. This would imply that the object is garbage. Note that this sort of optimization is only allowed if references are on the stack, not stored in the heap.

If your method A has only dead variables referring to the stream, then it won't obstruct its collection.

Note, however, that that means local variables: if you have fields which refer to the stream (including closed-over local variables from a method enclosing a nested class), then this doesn't apply; i don't think the JVM is allowed to treat these as dead. In other words, here:

```
public Callable<String> foo(final Object o) {
    return new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() throws InterruptedException {
            String s = o.toString();
            Thread.sleep(1000000);
            return s;
        }
    };
}
```

The object `o` cannot be collected until the anonymous `Callable` is collected, even though it is never used after the `toString` call, because there is a synthetic field referring to it in the `Callable`.

Comment: OK, this is extremely helpful. Do you know if Sun's JVM in recent incarnations actually implements this optimization?

Comment: I believe it does. An optimising compiler breaks the link between source variables and stack frame locations anyway (variables will sometimes be in registers, and different variables may occupy the same position in the stack frame at different times). As a result, to allow GC to happen correctly at all, there need to be fairly precise stack maps. IANAHotSpotDeveloper, though!